# Dewpoint of water in relation to composition of atmosphere

Tags: thermodynamics, water, gas-laws, phase-diagram

A couple of colleagues and I were talking about the nature of dewpoints, specifically the dewpoint of water in relation to the chemical composition of the atmosphere in a closed space.

If I remember my theory, then the chemical composition of the atmosphere should not have any impacts on the dewpoint of the water (assuming ideal gas law and that the atmosphere won't react with the water vapors)

My colleagues disagree with this, as they are of the opinion that different gasses can hold different concentrations of water vapor, e.g. $\ce{CO2}$ versus $\ce{N2}.$ As such, they argue that water would "*crash out*" of the gas phase at higher temperatures in atmospheres that could "*hold less water*".

Instead of wasting countless hours on research, I thought I might as well ask you brilliant people, if any of you could settle this dispute, or point me in a direction where an answer could be found.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How does composition of air affect vapor saturation limit?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/29177/how-does-composition-of-air-affect-vapor-saturation-limit)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Gases do not hold water vapor. Vapor is gas on its own. Neither oxygen nor nitrogen need other gases to hold them either. Gases are mutually toward each other just  bystanders. Vapor can be present in vacuum alone.

The [dewpoint](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dew_point) is the temperature, at which would liquid water have the same [saturated vapor pressure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vapour_pressure_of_water) as the [partial pressure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_pressure) of vapor present in the existing gaseous phase. If such vapor comes to contact with surface of temperature at or below the vapor dewpoint, part of vapor starts to condense, until the surface temperature is above the new dewpoint of vapor with lower partial pressure.

At special conditions near the liquid [critical point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Critical_point_(thermodynamics)), the dewpoint does depend on other gases, but in sense of total pressure. Or if there is strong interaction between gases. But neither of it is the case of water vapor in air near ambient conditions.

Comment: Somewhat related to deviations from independent vapor pressures are your answers to [Can precipitation occur in states of matter other than liquids?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/142441/16035) and [Why exactly does high pressure (72 bar) nitrous oxide's pseudocritical¹ temperature drop so far when oxygen is added to make 50%v/v mixture? (Entonox)](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/142526/16035)

Comment: @uhoh Yes, they are, I did not want to go to these details here

Comment: yep, but I have a hunch at least some readers of this answer will enjoy doing so in the future ;-)